# NameError: global name 'log_runtime' is not defined on scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I installed scapy and it works fine when i'm running it directly.
But when im trynig to write scripts with it it gives me an error.
I wrote a simple code but cant get it to work.

**Code:**

```
from scapy.all import *

packets = sniff(count=1)
packets.show()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Amir/PycharmProjects/ClientAndServer/mim.py", line 3, in 
<module>
packets = sniff(count=1)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\compatibility.py", 
line 177, in sniff
log_runtime.info('Sniffing on %s' % conf.iface)
NameError: global name 'log_runtime' is not defined
```

What should I do? couldn't find a solution...

Comment: Version of `scapy` ??

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug in your code, but a bug in Scapy itself.

This bug has been fixed, so you should probably be fine with getting the latest development version from the [official repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy).